# Django Template and Bootstrap Tables

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I have a django queryset that looks something like this

```
Group Label Name
A     1     Jack
A     2     Ryan
B     2     Alice
C     1     Sam
B     1     Mark
...
```

Basically, what I am attempting to do in my html, is create 6 small tables (2 rows of 3 tables). However, I want the first table to be Group A sorted by Label #, the second to be Group B sorted by Label #, etc.

I could bite the bullet and do 6 different django querysets, but this seems inefficient.

My initial thought was to have some counter in the django template to keep track of whether or not to start a new row. However, I am not sure if there is a way to filter & sort in the django template instead of the view.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. Order the queryset the way you want (sorted by group, then by label) by using the [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) operation.
2. In your template, use the [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) conditional to test to see when you have a different group. In that case, you output the table tags as necessary.

Example of item 2 above:

```
{% for object in queryset %}
  {% ifchanged obj.group %}
  <table>
  {% endifchanged %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ obj.label }}</td>
      <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% ifchanged obj.group %}
  </table>
  {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, except the last `ifchanged` doesn't work. I removed that section and added a `</table>` BEFORE `<table>` to close the previous table if group has changed. I still have to figure out how to make the columns and rows with bootstrap